# Unable to communicate from view controller to model

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I'm unable to call a method or create a variable on my view controller. I'm using the following code but it doesn't work.

```
// MODEL
@interface MyModel : NSObject
-(void)awesome;
@end

@implementation MyModel
-(void)awesome {
    NSLog(@"awesome");
}
@end

// VIEW CONTROLLER
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyModel *modelObject;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize modelObject;
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.modelObject awesome];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewDidLoad lacks a `self.modelObject = [MyModel new];`. Without it, modelObject is nil, and ignores the call to awesome. That's also why creating a variable and assigning a value didn't work.

Comment: O thats right thanks so much! i want to thumbs up you but I'm only a 9 reputation!

Comment: No problem, welcome to Stackoverflow and good luck on future iOS endeavors. Note that if the answer solved your problem, you can click on the check mark beside it to mark it as accepted.